# Should Return to the Page Even Without Login in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am working on laravel 5.4 project. I want to access some pages even without logged in but it always redirect to the login page. Here's my code. Is there anything i can do in middleware? Can you guys help me with this? i'm not really good in laravel. Thank you in advance guys.

**Route**

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('pages.index');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/admin_dashboard', 'HomeController@admin_dashboard');
Route::get('/admin_course_category', 'HomeController@admin_course_category');

Route::get('/modal_add_course_category', 'HomeController@modal_add_course_category');
Route::post('/save_category', 'HomeController@save_category');


//header routes
Route::get('/ak_news', 'HomeController@ak_news');
```

**Controller**

```php
public function ak_news()
{
    $newscategory = DB::table('tak_news_category')->get();

    $news = DB::table('tak_news')
        ->select('tak_news.*', 'tak_news.id as newsid', 'tak_news_category.id', 'tak_news_category.tak_news_category')
        ->join('tak_news_category', 'tak_news_category.id', '=', 'tak_news.tak_category_id')
        ->whereRaw('MOD(tak_news.id, 2) = 0')
        ->get();

    $news1 = DB::table('tak_news')
        ->select('tak_news.*', 'tak_news.id as newsid', 'tak_news_category.id', 'tak_news_category.tak_news_category')
        ->join('tak_news_category', 'tak_news_category.id', '=', 'tak_news.tak_category_id')
        ->inRandomOrder()->limit(1)
        ->whereRaw('MOD(tak_news.id, 1) = 0')
        ->get();
    $news2 = DB::table('tak_news')
        ->select('tak_news.*', 'tak_news.id as newsid', 'tak_news_category.id', 'tak_news_category.tak_news_category')
        ->join('tak_news_category', 'tak_news_category.id', '=', 'tak_news.tak_category_id')
        ->inRandomOrder()->limit(1)
        ->get();

    $latestnews = DB::table('tak_news')
        ->select('tak_news.*', 'tak_news.id as newsid', 'tak_news_category.id', 'tak_news_category.tak_news_category')
        ->join('tak_news_category', 'tak_news_category.id', '=', 'tak_news.tak_category_id')
        ->orderBY('tak_news.id', 'DESC')
        ->limit(4)
        ->get();

    $editors = DB::table('tak_news')
        ->select('tak_news.*', 'tak_news.id as newsid', 'tak_news_category.id', 'tak_news_category.tak_news_category')
        ->join('tak_news_category', 'tak_news_category.id', '=', 'tak_news.tak_category_id')
        ->where('tak_news.id', '=', '6')
        ->get();

    return view('pages.news_page', compact('newscategory', 'news', 'news1', 'news2', 'latestnews', 'editors'));
}
```

**View layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <!-- Mobile Specific Meta -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Favicon-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/fav.png">
    <!-- Author Meta -->
    <meta name="author" content="colorlib">
    <!-- Meta Description -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <!-- Meta Keyword -->
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <!-- meta character set -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Site Title -->
    <title>yeah</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,400,300,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--
    CSS
    ============================================= -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/linearicons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nice-select.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>

        <div class="container main-menu" id="main-menu">
            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <nav id="nav-menu-container">
                    <ul class="nav-menu">
                        <li class="menu-active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="archive.html">Archive</a></li>
                        <li><a href="category.html">Category</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-has-children"><a href="">Post Types</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="standard-post.html">Standard Post</a></li>
                            <li><a href="image-post.html">Image Post</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery-post.html">Gallery Post</a></li>
                            <li><a href="video-post.html">Video Post</a></li>
                            <li><a href="audio-post.html">Audio Post</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                </nav><!-- #nav-menu-container -->
                <div class="navbar-right">
                    <form class="Search">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control Search-box" name="Search-box" id="Search-box" placeholder="Search">
                        <label for="Search-box" class="Search-box-label">
                            <span class="lnr lnr-magnifier"></span>
                        </label>
                        <span class="Search-close">
                            <span class="lnr lnr-cross"></span>
                        </span>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    @yield('content')

    <!-- start footer Area -->
    <footer class="footer-area section-gap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 single-footer-widget">
                    <h4>Top Products</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Managed Website</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Manage Reputation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Power Tools</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Marketing Service</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 single-footer-widget">
                    <h4>Quick Links</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Brand Assets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Investor Relations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 single-footer-widget">
                    <h4>Features</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Brand Assets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Investor Relations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 single-footer-widget">
                    <h4>Resources</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Guides</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Research</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Experts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Agencies</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 single-footer-widget">
                    <h4>Instragram Feed</h4>
                    <ul class="instafeed d-flex flex-wrap">
                        <li><img src="img/i1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/i2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/i3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/i4.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/i5.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/i6.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/i7.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/i8.jpg" alt=""></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-bottom row align-items-center">

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 footer-social">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-behance"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- End footer Area -->
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBhOdIF3Y9382fqJYt5I_sswSrEw5eihAA"></script>
    <script src="js/easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
    <script src="js/superfish.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mn-accordion.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.nice-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mail-script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Hope you can help me guys. Thank you.

Comment: You might have place your route inside middleware auth instead of middleware web? Middleware auth requires authenticated user to access to the route while middleware web doesn't requires login to access the route.

Comment: how will i do that sir?

Comment: I would need to look at your route file

Comment: okay sir i will update my code above...

Comment: @LimKeanPhang i already updated my route above sir.

Comment: I believe its because of `HomeController`. There may be a constructor there that uses middleware `auth`, can you post the HomeController code

Comment: @KevinRED woaahhh yes it has...glad you comment this.... it saves me. super thank you!

Comment: I've change my controller without uses the middleware auth...and it works!

Comment: Glad I could help you

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php

    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages.index');
    });

    //header routes
    Route::get('/ak_news', 'HomeController@ak_news')->middleware('web');

    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('/admin_dashboard', 'HomeController@admin_dashboard');
    Route::get('/admin_course_category', 'HomeController@admin_course_category');

    Route::get('/modal_add_course_category', 'HomeController@modal_add_course_category');
    Route::post('/save_category', 'HomeController@save_category');
```

Comment: it's the same sir. It redirects to the login page.